# Why can't I upgrade my kernel via the terminal?

Tags: 11.04, kernel, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “dist-upgrade” and why does it upgrade more than “upgrade”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade)

If I type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` I can only see that the kernel packages are kept back, and not installed. As the screenshot shows.

[image]

If I then start the update manager I can install the kernel, with no problems at all. As the second screenshot shows.

[image]

### Why is this?

Comment: Maybe you can with `aptitude`.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/81585/10698
THis question covers the same grounds and will produce the same answer. This is a dupe, but a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is why!

The kernel is a new package and not an upgrade of an old one, this is why you can't use the command `upgrade` that upgrades/updates packages. You need to use the command `dist-upgrade` to install new packages.

When you have updated to the new kernel you can run the old one as well. That's why it's a new package and not just a upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

This is the difference between `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`. The first never install new packages.

Comment: doesn't dist-upgrade upgrade to a new distribution like 11.10?
Because I have installed new kernel updates via the terminal before it only took a week more, before I could.

Comment: @Alvar: absolutely no! One of the more misunderstood concepts

Comment: Could you explain the differences so we know how to think/not think?

Comment: @Alvar: see this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade, cannot write more from an android :)

Comment: I add an explaining answer, since you couldn't :).