# How do I download an Ubuntu 12.04 image with all updates so far?

Tags: 12.04, updates

If I would like to install 12.04 on September 2012 on several machines, is it possible to get an image with all the latest updates so far, so that I don't have to download and install the updates after installation?

Answer (score 1):

**If** you are going to install **Ubuntu 12.04 in September** then you need to Download the [Ubuntu 12.04.1](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseSchedule) edition  (called as **Point Release**) about to release on **23rd August** containing bug fixes and updates integrated till that period.

As far as forward updates are concerned , it depends on Newer version of applications to get released in that time frame , so it would be comparatively less against 12.04.

---

[What are point releases in LTS versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/whats-the-deal-with-point-releases-in-lts-versions)