# Do I need to reinstall my 12.04 desktop to get 12.04.1, which was released today?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the deal with point releases in LTS versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/whats-the-deal-with-point-releases-in-lts-versions)

The first LTS I ever installed was this latest one. I got word that the maintenance update 12.04.1 was released today. Should I download Precise again from Ubuntu? Or are all the updates since April covered in this latest release?

Comment: You don't need to. Just apply system updates the normal way and you will be fine.

Comment: [What's the deal with point releases?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/whats-the-deal-with-point-releases-in-lts-versions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, if you have been updating your 12.04 then you will already be sitting at 12.04.1.

The 12.04.1 install CD is mainly for people downloading Ubuntu and to save them installing all of the updates up 'til now.

Comment: I see. I'm glad I can stay put on 12.04 right now. Thanks!

Comment: 12.04.1 is mainly for people that update from LTS to LTS ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are NOT guaranteed to have latest version.

Open a terminal session and do the following at the prompt:
sudo apt-get upgrade        and then press return
enter your password at the prompt       and then
press Y to the question Y/N

once done then enter at the prompt:
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

and then press Y to yhe question Y/N      and then
enter at the prompt:
reboot

You are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do that please check your version first. Open terminal and type following command:

```
uname -a; cat /etc/lsb-release
```

Sample output from mine:

```
r00t@penreturns:~$ uname -a; cat /etc/lsb-release 
Linux penreturns 3.4.1-030401-generic #201206041411 SMP Mon Jun 4 18:12:24 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS"
r00t@penreturns:~$
```