# Is the update for a point release automatic or should I download and install?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

Through "System Settings" > "Details", it says Ubuntu 12.04.
I saw that a new version of 12.04-12.04.1-have been released.

Have "Update Manager" already update/upgrade my version? Or should I download and install?

Thanks for your Answers.

EDIT:
Terminal:

```
ubuntu@CandyCanDoIt:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
ubuntu@CandyCanDoIt:~$
```

"Details" in "System Settings":
[image]

Just uploading:
[image]

2)
[image]

3)
[image]

4)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command in the terminal:

```
lsb_release -a
```

You'll be able to see the version in *Description*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! 
_
ubuntu@CandyCanDoIt:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release: 12.04
Codename: precise
ubuntu@CandyCanDoIt:~$

Comment: I also edit my question with the terminal and deatails. and i'm accepting. thanks (:

Answer (score 2):

Install updates using "Update Manager" is enough. It will install new added package in Ubuntu 12.04.1 for you. Be sure you Ubuntu is always update.

Comment: Thanks. That means that "details" show 12.04 for both versions, right?

Comment: No it is not. You can see this link to know about point releases in LTS versions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/whats-the-deal-with-point-releases-in-lts-versions

Comment: I edit my question. termianl and details. I guess it normal. is'nt it?


also read everything in the link and now I know a lot more on point releases for LTS. Thanks.