# apt-get upgrade says sudo needs to be upgraded, is this correct?

Tags: 10.04, server, sudo

I have a Ubuntu Server running 10.04 - to be precise, `Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS` according to `lsb_release -a`.

I just ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and got this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-image-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  sudo
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 328kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.3kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

It seemed weird to me that only one package would need to be upgraded in a new version. I looked for a changelog on the Ubuntu site and the most recent one is for the version I have, [10.04.4](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseNotes/ChangeSummary/10.04.4), and makes no mention of `sudo` at all.

Is all correct here or is there something I should be worried about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The update to `sudo` you have there is just a regular update announced [in this mail](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lucid-changes/2012-December/013391.html). To verify what versions of `sudo` are installed and available, check out the power of `apt-cache policy` (this works for any package), e.g.:

```
$ apt-cache policy sudo
sudo:
  Installed: 1.8.3p1-1ubuntu3.3
  Candidate: 1.8.3p1-1ubuntu3.3
  Version table:
 *** 1.8.3p1-1ubuntu3.3 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.8.3p1-1ubuntu3.2 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.8.3p1-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

From your question I also assume that you would have expected more updates for a point release. Well, `10.04.4` or a `.5` if that would be planned, is not a real "release" like a complete new version of Ubuntu to where you get a whole pile of new updates. Instead, you've already received the updates during the last months and once the release team determines it's time for a new point release, ISOs get updated as a "point release". The update for `sudo` you got is just an additional update to the 10.04.4 release. It will not be included in any new point release, as `.4` is [the last one](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidReleaseSchedule) in the `10.04` series.

Please refer to these links for more information:

- [What are point releases in LTS versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/whats-the-deal-with-point-releases-in-lts-versions) - on what point releases are
- [Ubuntu Wiki /PointReleaseProcess](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PointReleaseProcess) - on the process

Answer (score 0):

In fact you don't need to worry, although it's a little bit strange that just one package is to be upgraded, but as this package is sudo, maybe upgrading it and then performing `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` again you will be presented to more packages to upgrade.

If you remain in doubt check Software Sources and `/etc/apt/sources.list` to see if the repositories that you use are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

sudo is a package just like any other and occasionally a newer version needs to be updated. I suggest you:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```