# What is a Ubuntu Point Release? How many point releases will Ubuntu 12.04 have?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the deal with point releases in LTS versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/whats-the-deal-with-point-releases-in-lts-versions)

I saw on planet ubuntu that there is a new point release coming out soon for Ubuntu 12.04.1.

What is a point release?

How often to these updates come out?

Are they upgrades to the kernel version? Or just packages? Will the system perform better after a point release?