# How do I update from my current Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS to Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS?

Tags: updates

How do I update from my current Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS to Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS?

Currently:

Release 12.04 (precise) 32-bit

Kernel Linux 3.2.0-38-generic-pae

GNOME 3.4.2

I boot to Ubuntu 12.04.1 using LVPM created by Wubi.

Answer (score 3):

You simply upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you are not familiar with the command line, just use the Update Manager to install updates.

Downloadable versions like 12.04.1 and 12.04.2 avoid a large update situations after a fresh install. Also this is useful for computers without or with a slow internet connection. The update manager is always your source for update information. I'm not sure about this, but I think it will even tell you if support for your LTS gets dropped and ask you to upgrade to a new LTS.

Comment: Ran that in Terminal and got. :~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: That simply means that you have your system fully updated. As explained in the answer, the ".2" in 12.04.2 means that a lot of updates and upgrades have been put in the installation disc image, so you don't have to install _everything_ that has been updated since Ubuntu 12.04 was first launched. If you ever used that other O.S., this is somewhat similar to buying the OS+"service pack" as opposed to installing it from your existing system (which would be your case).

Comment: I ran Update Manager first thing and nothing came up.  In Software Sources I have it set to "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version": For long-term support versions.  When I have it set to "For any new version" it shows me New Ubuntu release '12.10' is available.

Comment: You can upgrade to 12.10, but 12.10 is not a LTS. If you so desire, be sure to back up your data before you upgrade.

Comment: I wish to upgrade to 12.04.2 LTS if possible and not 12.10

Comment: As has been explained, you are already on "12.04.2", nothing more needs to be done. See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/whats-the-deal-with-point-releases-in-lts-versions

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for all your help and clarification.  I really appreciate your time folks.