# Will 4000 MB be enough for all the download work needed to install Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

I am a Windows user and I am looking forward to using Ubuntu 12.04, however there are some difficulties I want to discuss. First off I am using a Pentium 4 PC RAM 4 GB and 160 GB hard disk, processor 3.00 GHz. Will Ubuntu run seamlessly and faster than Windows 7 that I have? Secondly, I access the Internet using HUAWEI Tata Photon+ device. Will that work on Ubuntu? Most importantly, I have a balance of 4000 MB left, will that be enough for all the download work needed(say by the exe installer).

Thanks a lot fellas.

Comment: Please do not ask more than one question per post :)

Comment: I did that on all other SE sites. Sorry, if it was not allowed here.

Comment: @AshishGaurav That's everywhere on the SE network sites and how Q&A sites work in general.

Comment: It will depend on your configuration how fast ubuntu runs. With your setup you might consider a less-resource intensive desktop environment than unity. [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) is a great option for older hardware.

Comment: Internet download allowance: 4000 MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4000 MB should be WAY more than enough to download Ubuntu... if you're planning on downloading extra software after you download Ubuntu, it really depends upon what the software is.

Answer (score 2):

Size of iso is near ~750 MB . And you may need extra band width for installing additional tools . Your system specs are enough to run ubuntu smoothly .

Comment: Won't the iso file download anything else during Ubuntu installation?

Comment: @AshishGaurav Yes, it will. It will download and install essential updates. Be sure to use a 12.04.2 (note the .2) ISO to minimize the amount of packages for that. The .2 [point release](http://askubuntu.com/q/106159/88802) is the latest updated ISO for 12.04 at the time of writing.

Comment: Any idea on the size of updates? I am extremely limited to 4000 MB!

Comment: I don't know the exact size, but it will be defnitly less than 700 MB for a fresh install ,so don't worry about it, the available bandwidth is more than enough :)

Answer (score 2):

Yep.  4GB of data is more than enough.  I installed it using 1.5GB of data transferred, and had no trouble at all.

Comment: Re-reading the answer - do you mean 4GB of data to download or 4GB of RAM/memory?

Comment: I mean 4GB of data to download.

Comment: I clearly wrote 4000 MB 'balance', and I'm sorry if that confuses. Anyways if that is going to work, that is all right.

Comment: @BobbyPhoenix do you mean 4GB of data to download or 4GB of RAM/memory? I hoped you mean data download as that's what the question is about. I've edited your answer to reflect that. Revert if 1.5GB of RAM/memory is what you meant.

Comment: @gertvdijk Yes that is what I meant.  Data, not memory.  As in I downloaded Ubuntu to a USB stick that was 8GB, and it fit no problem with room to spare.  I actually just checked it, and Ubuntu installed at a total of 1.8GB leaving me 6.2GB free.