# How do I upgrade from an LTS release to the next point release?

Tags: upgrade, release-management

I have so many bugs in my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS that I have lost count and the energy to fix them. The system won't upgrade properly or even update packages any more. When I log in I get a black screen first. Then, if I press return, I get to the log in screen. When I get to the desktop,some times my folders aren't there - so I use gnome-do to find a folder and suddenly the stuff appears on my desktop out of the blue.

I have lived with these bugs perhaps just a few months after 12.04 LTS came out and it's the first version of Ubuntu I have ever had problems with.

My question is two-fold:

1. What's the best way of cleaning up this mess?
2. If I already have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and have a CD with Ubuntu 12.04.3, can it upgrade my old system with that CD without making a new partition?

I just want to get rid of all these bugs so I can go ahead and do my work.

Comment: what's wrong with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` ?

Comment: if I use sudo apt-get update I get errors. I can't even access synaptick package manager anymore because it shuts down after a fatal error. The closest I have gotten is a partial upgrade - and I am not even sure what that did. It sure didn't fix any of the bugs. I haven't tried sudo apt-get dist-upgrade. That may be the answer?

Comment: don't even consider an upgrade if it's so broken. Do a clean install of 12.04/13.04

Answer (score 3):

**General answer:**

You don't need to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.04.3. These so called point releases are only important for when you are installing so you don't download 6, 12, 18 months worth of updates. If you update your system normally you are already using the same packages as the point releases.

More information about what are the [point releases](https://askubuntu.com/q/106159/169736).

**Specific case answer:**

As Alvar pointed out, if you system is broken you should backup your personal data and install from zero. This assures you the stability of your system. I would download the Ubuntu 12.04.3 image to perform the install, so you don't need to install all the updates of the packages since April 2012.

> What's the best way of cleaning up this mess?

Reinstalling.

> If I already have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and have a CD with Ubuntu 12.04.3, can it upgrade my old system with that CD without making a new partition?

If it's so broken, the best option is not.