# How to upgrade to a point release from the same base release (12.04 to 12.04.03)

Tags: upgrade

I have ubuntu 12.04 (original) installed on a server.

How do I upgrade this to 12.04.03?

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate to any of the linked questions. We should reopen it for people asking on how to upgrade to a point release. Alternatively the answer here should be merged to http://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/what-are-point-releases-in-lts-versions and the title of this Q should be edited with "... and how do I upgrade to them?".