# Difference between the host and the guest OS kernel versions

Tags: kernel, package-management, virtualization

I had installed Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit on my Laptop (host OS) when it was released (around April, 2012) and after applying all the patches (sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade), the version of Linux kernel is

```
uname -r
3.2.0-53-generic
```

Recently I downloaded ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso and used if for installing a guest OS on top of VirtualBox, the default Linux kernel is

```
uname -r
3.8.0-29-generic
```

And 3.8.0-34 is available on doing a dist-upgrade on the guest.

Why is not the kernel version getting upgraded to 3.8.0-* on the host OS even after a dist-upgrade? I am getting the rest of the upgrades though.

Also, because of the kernel mismatch I am not able to install the VirtualBox guest additions.

Answer (score 1):

When 12.04 was first released, the Linux kernel was about 3.2, 3.3. Since then you haven't updated your kernel stack, hence you still use 3.2. But, [point releases](https://askubuntu.com/q/106159/169736) which you installed recently has the latest available kernel (and others packages) which is 3.8. This is to prevent that .5, 1 and 1.5 years of updates.

In your laptop you can install the latest kernel available using:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-raring
```

Comment: As mentioned in the query, I did a `apt-get dist-upgrade` on the host, so this should have upgraded the kernels also. Also, in the synaptic linux-generic points to 3.2.0.57.68 and not the latest 3.8.0-29 version of Kernel.

Comment: @PraveenSripati even if you do `dist-upgrade` if you don't have the meta package installed it will not upgrade the kernel out of the `3.2`. If you do `apt-cache search image | grep linux-image` you will notice several kernel versions that you don't have installed.

Comment: As I said,  in the synaptic linux-generic points to the old 3.2.0.57.68. So, `sudo apt-get install linux-generic` installed 3.2.0.57.68 and not the latest kernel. I did a `sudo apt-cache search linux-image | grep 34` and I see `linux-image-3.8.0-34-generic` as one of it. I was able to manually update the kernel with `sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.8.0-34-generic`, but it's a pain.

Comment: Then, what's the problem? Just install `linux-image-3.8.0-34-generic` or the package that depends of it (I don't use LTS so I wouldn't know) but a simple `apt-cache rdepends linux-image-3.8.0-34-generic` will tell you exactly what package is (I hope is not something like `linux-image-lts-raring-generic`)

Comment: `apt-cache rdepends linux-image-3.8.0-34-generic` returns `linux-image-generic-lts-raring` and I am using `Precise`. Not sure, but I am missing something. `linux-generic` should point to the latest kernel on any version and it is not.

Comment: That is. When you try to install a kernel that is not provided by the version of ubuntu, it comes with the latest Hardware Enablement Stack http://askubuntu.com/q/248914/169736. This is why the different package name, since you are installing the kernel provided in raring.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12084/discussion-between-praveen-sripati-and-braiam)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Ubuntu Documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop)

By default, the 12.04.3 point release will ship with a newer 3.8 Ubuntu kernel from Ubuntu 13.04, and a matching X.org stack. This is based on the 3.8.0 Extended Upstream Stable Kernel Release. The purpose of providing a newer kernel in the 12.04.3 point release is for hardware enablement.

More [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).