# LTS for 12.04.02

Tags: 12.04

Since 12.04 is an LTS version, does that means that it will have long support no matter what 12.04.X it is?

E.g.: Can I have 12.04.01 and still be supported until 2017?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. GNU/Linux Ubuntu *"Precise Pangolin"* 12.04 LTS is supported until April 2017.
Which means that we get updates/security fixes for 5 years from the date of release. We can set Ubuntu to check for updates every day, every 2 days, weekly, every fortnight or never.

Please see the following links:

- [Precise Upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades)
- [Ubuntu LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)

As soon as GNU/Linux Ubuntu *"Trusy Tahr"* 14.04 LTS is released you can upgrade from 12.04 LTS direct to 14.04 LTS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can have Ubuntu 12.04.01 point LTS release still  be supported until 2017.

> Like other LTS releases, 12.04 will include point releases that bundle updates to shorten downloads for users installing the release later in its lifecycle.
>
> The point releases and dates are: 12.04.1 (23 August 2012), 12.04.2 (14 February 2013), 12.04.3 (scheduled for release on 22 August 2013, but actually released on 23 August 2013) and 12.04.4 (6 February 2014). No further point releases of Ubuntu 12.04 are scheduled.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases)

[What are point releases in LTS versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/whats-the-deal-with-point-releases-in-lts-versions)

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you installed 12.04.y and you upgrade it to be up-to-date then you are basically running the latest 12.04.x. The only things which not get automatically updated to the latest 12.04.x are the kernel and the X-server. The latter ones don't get automatically updated because of the *If it ain't broke, don't fix it* policy.

You can check this if you run `lsb_release -a` on your machine. I installed 12.04 in April 2012 and now for me this is the output of that command:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

I only installed the important and recommended upgrades but you can see it reports 12.04.3 LTS for me.

If you want to get the kernel and X-server present in a point release released after your installation you just have to opt into the hardware enablement stack for Precise by installing the kernel and X-server of a point release. For more info on the hardware enablement stack and how to opt into it visit [this site](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

But you can keep your kernel version and X-server of course, those are supported for 5 years too. From the aforementioned site:

> *The original 12.04 stack in Precise will remain supported for the usual 5yr life cycle of the LTS release.*