# Debian Unstable equivalent in Ubuntu

Tags: release-management

I want use Ubuntu with the latest stable *software* instead of latest stable *packages*. As far as I'm aware the Debian equivalent is the Debian Unstable version.

- Is the daily live images released by Ubuntu equivalent?
- Does it continue updating with the latest stable software after a new stable Ubuntu version is released? As in, with the daily live installation of Trusty, does it continue updating with development software after Trusty goes golden?

I'm not sure, but I think I read on Mark Shuttleworth's blog that the development version of Ubuntu is stable enough to use on desktops. I'm neither trusting nor doubting the statement, but that post seemed to imply of continuous development releases like a rolling release.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: I believe the live images would indeed be equivalent to unstable. Also, I wouldn't say that the development version of Ubuntu (as in Trusty or the U-Series when Trusty is released) is stable enough to use on a needed desktop.

Comment: @saiarcot895 It's stability is not my primary concern. I just regular sstable software updates. Do you know if it'll continue updating after Trusty is released? And will the current beta 2 release behave the same?

Comment: If it's just software updates, I would instead use PPAs or install software outside of the repos. The development version will also involve updates to more critical components of Ubuntu/Linux itself, which may or may not bring problems (inability to use Ubuntu). Also, there is no guarantee that the software updates will work correctly, as there may be bugs. Also, I don't see how stability of the system as a whole is not a concern when you need stable software updates; if you can't use the system, what's the point of having the latest LibreOffice?

Comment: Upgrading to Trusty now won't automatically move you over to U-series. Using the daily images and upgrading for each image might, I think, keep you on the latest development version.

Comment: @saiarcot895 You see, system updates (kernel, drivers, etc) is precisely the sort of updates I'm looking for, and I'm unlikely to find everything in PPA (yes, I'm aware of Ubuntu Mainline PPA and Oibaf PPA). This is for testing purposes, so I'm not about to upgrade from an existing installation. So if installing a daily image keeps me up-to-date beyond T-series, I'm ready to do a fresh install immediately.

Comment: Ah, ok, if it's purely for testing purposes, then it's fine, but I believe you will have to keep installing daily images (or maybe the `do-release-upgrade -d` can take care of a transition from Trusty to U-series).

Comment: @saiarcot895 I don't mean to discredit your statements, but do you have anything more concrete? I always try to do something after ascertaining that I'll be able to do exactly as I want. Also, you're welcome to post an answer. Can't mark it solved without any.

Comment: If I had something concrete, I would post it as an answer. :)

Comment: [Mark's interview](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/news/interviews/386080/mark-shuttleworth-interview-taking-ubuntu-beyond-desktops) about release updates all the time.

Comment: Packages *are* software, so it makes no sense the way you seem to differentiate the two.

Comment: im using 14.04 and I have to run updates and upgrade multiple times per day, seems kinda a rolling release. It's just a beta and things will change. I wish ubuntu was a rolling release, that thing got me thinking to go for debian, like solydk

Comment: @psusi You're incorrect. Package is more than the software, it contains the the initial configuration and set up scripts for the software it installs. Sometimes software with their stock configuration may not play well with an OS, the packages are configured to take care of that. You'll notice there's `ubuntu` and some numbers at the end of package names. Those are package versions, created for Ubuntu.

Comment: @Oxwivi, sure, but it still makes no sense to differentiate them the way the OP did.  If you want the latest software, then you want the latest package of that software.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @SylvainPineau I'm no longer as active on AU as I used to be for various reasons, but thank you, I'll read that when I someone does answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

For developement releases, the vast majority of Ubuntu packages are imported from Debian Unstable/Testing:

> Prior to
>   [DebianImportFreeze](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebianImportFreeze), new
>   versions of packages will be automatically imported from Debian where
>   they have not been customized for Ubuntu, that is when the version
>   number of the package in the current Ubuntu development branch does
>   not contain the substring "ubuntu" and there is a newer version in
>   Debian. Imports from Debian are either from the unstable or testing
>   branch, depending on the release (see "Derives from:" field on
>   http://launchpad.net/ubuntu/ for more information).

For LTS releases, not only there are [SRU](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) for important bug fixes but [point releases](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/what-are-point-releases-in-lts-versions) are
also a way to get new hardware support, new drivers:

> On a regular basis, the LTS release gets a point update which includes
>   access to a new, current kernel (supporting new hardware without
>   regressing the old hardware on the previous kernel, which remains
>   supported), new OpenStack (via the Cloud Archive), and various other
>   elements.

**Sources:**

- http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1246
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
- [What is hardware enablement (HWE)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly: there is no equivalent to unstable ( where developers upload new packages all the time and you get them right away, never having to dist-upgrade ) in Ubuntu.  The closest thing is the current development release, which behaves as unstable does, until it becomes a stable release, at which point, you have to dist-upgrade to the new development release if you don't want to remain stable.

Comment: So, no automatic transition to new development release? :(

Comment: @Oxwivi, right.. of course it isn't that hard to manually transition once the new development release opens.

Comment: I think you use /devel/ instead of the animal name in your sources.list you just keep upgrading.

Comment: @JorgeCastro Is there any ISO preconfigured to do that? I know how to edit `sources.list`, but just asking. Feel free to post an answer.