# Does the package unattended-upgrades upgrade Major versions or just Minor ones

Tags: unattended-upgrades

I know this package can update minor version, say 12. 04. 02 to 12. 04. 04  and even bigger jobs. But does it also do Major version jumps - say version 12 to 13  or 14? Without any human interaction.

Thinking about making a private mirror and when I put version 14 (tahr) in the mirror the unattended-upgrades package should update all the slaves to 14 automagically.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the point release are relevant only for [fresh system installation proposes](https://askubuntu.com/a/106170/169736), there's no way to know "which point release" you are because the package manager isn't just aware of it.

Secondly, no, unattended-upgrades doesn't modify the repositories, so as long as you leave `trusty` or whatever the codename of the version of Ubuntu is, it will only upgrade to those packages that are available, using the equivalent of `apt-get upgrade`, ignoring those package that mustn't upgrade automatically.