# When will kernel 3.14 be available in the repositories?

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I see that kernel 3.14.1 is available for Trusty at

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

When will this kernel be available for upgrade via the Ubuntu repositories.

(I know that I can manually download and upgrade the kernel, but I'd rather get it as an update).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It never will. New kernels arrive at repositories of LTS versions when [point releases](https://askubuntu.com/q/106159/65926) come out. This is part of the [Hardware Enablement Stack](https://askubuntu.com/q/248914/65926).

According to the [14.04.x Ubuntu Kernel Support Schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2BAC8-Support.A14.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support), kernel 3.16 (from Ubuntu 14.10) will be available in Ubuntu 14.04.2 (due in Feb, 2015). But you don't have to reinstall your system, once 14.04.2 is out (and probably a few days before) just run the following to install kernel 3.16:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

Answer (score 1):

You can already get it by installing the following...

```
linux-generic-lts-utopic
linux-image-lts-utopic
linux-headers-lts-utopic
```

Just remove `linux-generic`, `linux-image-generic`, and `linux-headers-generic` first.  You don't need a PPA.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @eric-carvalho answer:

If you don't want to wait to run Utopic kernel until Feb 2015, you can add the Canonical Team PPA. But this is the PPA description:

### This ppa is used for building pre-release and test kernels.

### It IS NOT RECOMMENDED that you subscribe to this PPA.

If you're ok with that, add the PPA and install utopic kernel:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

Answer (score 0):

The image at [Kernel/LTSEnablementStack - Ubuntu Kernel Support section](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2BAC8-Support.Ubuntu_Kernel_Support) shows that the 3.16 kernel will come out first, along with 14.10, as an "Early Preview" from the "-updates pocket", i.e. the "recommended", non-security-related updates.  And in fact it is already there, currently as `linux-image-3.16.0-29-generic` though of course you'll want to install the generic package `linux-image-generic-lts-utopic` to keep up with updates to it.

Eric notes that 14.04.2 comes out in February.  Perhaps then the new kernel will be in another pocket, whatever that is....  Unfortunately I don't see any actual text at ubuntu.com which explains the "early preview" option any more, or uses the term "pocket" in this context.  So some more clarity would be welcome.