# How long are older point-releases of LTS supported?

Tags: lts, support

Ubuntu LTS versions receive 5 years of support.  Occasionally, new point-releases are made for LTS versions.  For example, Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS was released on July 24 2014, which replaces 14.04.

How long are security updates provided for the original 14.04 release (or other LTS versions)?  The [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) has no end of life date defined for 14.04.

**Edit:** [This answer explains](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/what-are-point-releases-in-lts-versions) that point-releases are just snapshots of the bug fixes released so far, thus all versions receive the same duration of support.

Comment: I edited the question to explain why this is a relevant question and is not answered by the answer this was marked a duplicate of.

Comment: From Lekensteyn's answer: *Each point release is merely a snapshot of updated packages in the LTS version at that time which includes security updates and bug fixes.* If you don't have the latest point release, Ubuntu will get exactly the same updates anyway, and the end of LTS support comes at the same time for all point releases that have the same release name (i.e. trusty, utopic, etc.). For all point releases of Ubuntu 14.04, the end of LTS is April, 2019. Point release = original release + some bundled updates,otherwise there's no difference between a point release and an original release

Comment: This is nonsense. Apache 2.2 was *never* available for Ubuntu 14.04. It was never available for 13.10 either. Since the past two releases, Ubuntu has been on Apache 2.4.X. Check the [changelogs](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1/changelog), if you wish.

Comment: If apache2 version 2.4.7 was a security fix, then that is not available in 14.04 LTS, thus contradicting your statement that 14.04 LTS will receive all the same updates.  14.04 and 14.04.1 are distince releases with different packages, thus I still find this a relevant question.  (Maybe the answer to this question is that both will receive bug fixes for the same time, but the point-releases also contain some additional goodies?)

Comment: Further nonsense. If you install Ubuntu using a 14.04.1 ISO and a 14.04 ISO, and do an `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade`, you'll end up with the same packages for Apache in both.

Comment: Sorry - my bad.  I was accidentally comparing 12.04 to 14.04.1.  Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: I updated the question to remove the incorrect statements there. Sorry for the hassle.