# Upgrade from 13.10 to 14.0.4.01 LTS Possible?

Tags: 14.04, lts, do-release-upgrade

My infrastructure is on AWS. All my ec2 server are running on ubuntu 13.10. Since 13.10 is EOL last year, i want to upgrade it to 14.04.01 LTS which has 5 year lifecycle.

**What i want:** i want to upgrade it to 14.04.01 LTS which has 5 year lifecycle.

**Problem:** When i run command ' do-release-upgrade' it shows me available version is 14.04.2.

But i dont want to upgrade it to 14.04.2 as it will be EOL in Aug 2016, instead i want to upgarde to 14.04.01 which will be EOL in 2019.

Can somebody please tell me how can i upgrade directly from 13.10 to 14.04.01 LTS.

Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS will be supported for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop.  The .01 or .02 is just an update.

Comment: I agree  with you as in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases.  So how should i upgrade to 14.04 from 13.10 with  "do-release-upgrade" ?  Or you are saying both 14.04.1 and 14.04.2 are also supported for 5 years. So if i upgrade to 14.04.2..i should be fine ..??     Thanks

Comment: I missed this 'Ubuntu Desktop' in your last comment. So what LTS version is available for server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are point releases in LTS versions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/what-are-point-releases-in-lts-versions)

Answer (score 0):

As it appears in this picture the versions of 14.04.X will have different version of the kernel so 14.0.4.1 will continue with the kernel of V3.13 till April 2019 while 14.04.2 will have 3.16 for 18 months then to be upgraded to 14.04.5 with the version of kernel o be applied then

For more info kindly check this [Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

[image: 14.04.X Kernel Support Schedule]

however if you still want to upgrade to 14.04.1 you may download the ISO Image from this [LINK](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.1/)  and perform Upgrading by using the CD image

Insert the live CD or boot from the live CD to start installing it will give a option of upgrading to 13.04 if we have a functional Internet connection only. It will automatically detect installed applications and install the updated version of your applications also.

If you download an ISO, the recommendation is to perform a md5sum check to ensure both the ISO downloaded and the burned CD are valid.
More Info About upgrading in this [LINK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: Since i am already running application on 50 Production machines and on 50 in other environments, my biggest pain is to upgrade them for every new release. That's why i am looking to sustain on a version which has longest EOL date. Do you think its a valid concern. Also do you think sticking to the kernel v3.13 for long time (2019) is a security risk ? Regarding upgrading from CD ISO, i dont think that will apply to AWS EC2. I may need to re-create with 14.0.4.1 AMI.

Comment: If you ask for what i see optimum . is to upgrade to 14.04.2  then to 14.04.5. That way you will always be on a supported LTS version with all the updates and new features . it's 1 extra step only but i see it deserves to take it

Comment: 3.13 is not a security risk. It will get security updates till EOL of 14.04. But still there is no much reson to stick onto it.

Comment: I will keep it open for some more hours.. just to see where i stand after all your brilliant answers.

Comment: **What should be my approach while upgrading a Production server from 13.10 to 14.04.2**.  _In my opinion_: `1) Update in /etc/apt/source.list to point to old-release 2) then update and upgrade the softwares 3) Create backup/ or server AMI and then 4) Finally run the upgrade and pray that the server upgrade and comes up fine`.                                                  Please point-out/add if anything missing.

Answer (score 0):

You did not quite understand it. 14.04.2 is LTS. It is just a service release of 14.04. Shorter life is only for kernel version, but it can be upgraded later. So just upgrade to 14.04.2.

Comment: 14.04.2 it's not just a service release it's a point release that uses HWE kernels. Quote: "LTS "point releases" often ship the latest hardware enablement stack. These are the Kernel, X server and graphics driver versions from the latest non-LTS, backported to the LTS. This allows people to keep using the same old software, supported for a long time, but with modern hardware support (and performance boosts from newer drivers/kernel/etc)."

Comment: **What should be my approach while upgrading a Production server from 13.10 to 14.04.2**

_In my opinion_:

`1) Update in /etc/apt/source.list to point to old-release
2) then update and upgrade the softwares
3) Create backup/ or server AMI and then
4) Finally run the upgrade and pray that the server upgrade and comes up fine.
`

Please point-out/add if anything missing.