# Will 14.04.3LTS automatic be upgraded in my 14.04 TS?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I read just now that Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS is released. I am now running 14.04LTS,and wonder whether this upgrade comes automatically to me via the Ubuntu software center updates? ; or do I have to manually download 14.04.3 and install?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are point releases in LTS versions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/what-are-point-releases-in-lts-versions)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to manually download and install 14.04.3. It will automatically be done through the Ubuntu software center.

---

If you want to perform the update right now, just run the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```