# Is it possible to upgrade to a specific LTS version?

Tags: upgrade

I have an Ubuntu server running `14.04.1 LTS` and I need to upgrade it to `14.04.3 LTS`. Is this even possible?

I tried running:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

But it failed with the following error:

```
Required depends is not installed

The required dependency 'apt (>= 1.0.1ubuntu2.13)' is not installed.
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Thu Jul 14 07:46:19 2016) ===
```

Comment: Is there any reason you need to update to 14.04.3 and not 14.04.4 (which is currently the newest version)?

Comment: @SledgeHammer: Yes, our production server uses `14.04.3` and I rather not touch that one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are point releases in LTS versions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/what-are-point-releases-in-lts-versions)

Comment: @Braiam - This topic explains what are point releases but not how to update to a specific one which is what **uvasal** needs.

Comment: @SledgeHammer "Each **point release is merely a snapshot of updated packages in the LTS version** at that time which includes security updates and bug fixes." There's no upgrade to a specific point release, the point release aren't relevant while upgrading, *just when installing*.

Comment: @Braiam: Exactly. So it's not possible and the answer to my question is not in the other topic. If anybody posts an answer, I will be happy to mark accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can **install** any specific release. You can find the one you are looking for [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.0/) website. Just install as usual (create usb/cd, boot, etc). yet, if you run upgrade/update, you will end up with the final point release anyway.

It is for this same reason that in the [official website](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) you will only see the final releases. Any previous one is override by an `apt-get upgrade/update` operation.