# How do I know what version `do-release-upgrade` will upgrade to?

Tags: apt, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I'm running Lubuntu LTS 14.04 and I'm looking to upgrade to the latest LTS (16.04). All upgrade guides (for example [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts)) seem to suggest that I should use the official upgrading script called `do-release-upgrade`.

But how do I know that this will take me from 14.04 to 16.04 and not some other version, like for example the latest release 16.10?

The output of `do-release-upgrade` itself does not seem to contain the version it's upgrading to. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to upgrade to a specific LTS version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/798456/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-to-a-specific-lts-version)

Comment: @George: I don't see how the linked question and its answer(s) cover or address this question.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I think it explains what one can do or expect when dist-upgrade is run

Answer (score 12):

You can check:

```
$ do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '17.04' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

Or run the upgrade and cancel:

```
$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [836 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,268 kB]
Fetched 1,269 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'zesty.tar.gz' against 'zesty.tar.gz.gpg'
extracting 'zesty.tar.gz'
[sudo] password for muru:
```

It's clear from both outputs that I'll be upgraded to 17.04 (`zesty`).

```
$ do-release-upgrade --help
Usage: do-release-upgrade [options]

Options:
...
  -c, --check-dist-upgrade-only
                        Check only if a new distribution release is available
                        and report the result via the exit code
```

Comment: Weird that that's not in `man do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: Odd. It's in `do-release-upgrade --help`. Probably worth filing a bug report.

Comment: Done:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1798425