# EOL Upgrade Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

Tags: 18.04, updates, do-release-upgrade

I would like to upgrade my Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver) to latest/greatest version because the current one is going to be EOL in May 2023. Any one done this upgrade please provide the steps.

However I tried upgrade my server using below command but it says my current OS is not LTS and I need to try to non-LTS. What is wrong?

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Comment: You should run these commands in order: `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt full-upgrade` and then `sudo do-release-upgrade` (do NOT use the `-d` option). Please provide output for each in your question. Thanks.

Comment: Also in any case, make sure you have a backup of your important data - just because...

Comment: Did you look at any of the release announcements or upgrade instructions, ie. most have this (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades) and other links which outline the procedure (*note: that link isn't all I'd read as others provide troubleshooting & other use-case scenarios*).

Comment: The `-d` option is used to *release-upgrade* to the *development* release; ie. from 23.04 to the current *mantic* release - thus it's **not** a *release-upgrade* you currently have available to you.  Your usage of `-d` is a user error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I know what version \`do-release-upgrade\` will upgrade to?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954578/how-do-i-know-what-version-do-release-upgrade-will-upgrade-to)

Comment: FYI:  If you found some *really old* documentation that said to use `-d` for the upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04, that only applied until 20.04.1 was released (ie. before https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/06/ubuntu-20-04-1-lts-released/) as the *development* status for the upgrade was removed [*days after that release actually*]. Ubuntu 20.04 is currently at [20.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I smoothly upgrade from one LTS to next LTS release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717827/can-i-smoothly-upgrade-from-one-lts-to-next-lts-release)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Answer (score 6):

You should normally not use the `-d` option with `do-release-upgrade`.

Let's check the [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html):

> ```
>  -d, --devel-release
>         If using the latest supported release, upgrade to the development release
> ```

The `-d` option should only be used when you are on the *latest* supported release (at this time Ubuntu 23.04), and want to upgrade to the next *development* release. In addition, the `-d` option will also be relevant *right after* the release of a new LTS version (say when Ubuntu 24.04 is released), and you want to upgrade an existing 22.04 version *before* the first point release (24.04.1) unlocks the LTS upgrade window (usually in August) - but this should be considered an advanced usecase.

Instead, you can use the `-c` option to check which version you will upgrade to:

> ```
>  -c, --check-dist-upgrade-only
>         Check only if a new distribution release is available and report the result via the exit code
> ```

So to verify the upgrade path run:

```
do-release-upgrade -c
```

Afterwards, perform a normal upgrade command with no options:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```