# Are 14.04 and 14.04.5 the same?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, amd-graphics

Many AMD users suggested I should use this operating system. Are 14.04 and 14.04.5 the same, and if not which should I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are point releases in LTS versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/what-are-point-releases-in-lts-versions)

Answer (score 4):

14.04 is the base version. 14.04.5 is the latest of 5 incremental updates to 14.04. It includes newer packages (maybe a newer kernel), but that's about it. 14.04.1-5 are there so that people can install 14.04 with the updates pre-packaged, so fewer updates are needed post-install.

So, yes, 14.04 and 14.04.5 are the same, because 14.04.5 *is* 14.04. It just has updated packages that those using the first release of 14.04 would have to install.

Comment: Basicly a better 14.04?

Comment: No, it actually is 14.04. Point releases (14.04.x) just come packaged with updates that have been released since 14.04 became available in April 2014.

Comment: Beyond 14.04.1, the point releases come with a new kernel release, so better for newer hardware, but you're back to 9 mo. support.