# Upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 final freeze to stable

Tags: upgrade, updates

The final freeze is out on 19th April, The stable release will out on 27th April. Is it a good idea to install final freeze and then update it to stable when out?

Or should I wait for the stable release?

**Why am I concerned?**

I have to setup a complete system, each and every application & package, plus a development environment. Most of the time there will be a potential issues in updating.

Comment: A few things. 1. "each and every application & package" - is this supposed to mean EVERY SINGLE PACKAGE installed? There are 66k packages in the Ubuntu repositories (universe, updates, multiverse, main). Over 100GB download and 250GB installed. You probably don't want this. 2. "potential issues in updating" - is this a question or a statement? 3. What is this system for? 4. Why would you want a development version? 5. At the end of the day, you are probably better off waiting for the stable release.

Comment: Who wouldn't want to wait for the stable release? Especially since it's only one week until the official 18.04 LTS release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a productive system, I recommend not rushing anything. Pre-release versions are not supposed to be stable and may contain many bugs.

Start testing 18.04 on a separate machine once it is officially released in a week. You should probably not consider upgrading your productive system before 18.04.1. By default, the `do-release-upgrade` tool [will not offer the upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/q/125392/367990) before the first [point-release](https://askubuntu.com/q/106159/367990) is out anyway.

---

For a development system, you could of course do it however you want. If you need it immediately, using the 18.04 beta instead of 17.10 or 16.04 for a week might be more reasonable. Keep in mind that you might encounter bugs though.

Comment: I just need that, You are right because alot of bugs are reported already.