# How do I disable updates in Ubuntu 16.04.4 to install Xilinx PetaLinux?

Tags: 16.04, updates

I am continuously getting a message asking to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04.4 to Ubuntu 16.04.5.  I would like to disable this message so I can keep using Ubuntu 16.04.4 to install Xilinx PetaLinux 2018.3.

The system requirements in the [documentation](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_3/ug1144-petalinux-tools-reference-guide.pdf) say that it requires version Ubuntu 16.05.4.

Comment: Hi, I want to install Xilinx petalinux 2018.3 in Ubuntu 18.04.4 which is compatible. According to user guide Xilinx UG1144 (v2018.3), only Ubuntu 18.04.3 and Ubuntu 18.04.4 are compatible operating systems and not Ubuntu 18.04.5. Therefore, I would like to keep Ubuntu 18.04.4 without upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.5.

Comment: 18.04.xx are only *point releases* -- The purpose of point releases is to consolidate updates so that when people install 16.04 in 2020, they don't have four years of updates.  18.04.5 is not a different release than 18.04.4.  They are the same. Can you cite your source? If it says that 18.04.5 is explicitly unsupported there must be some package because again, it's not any different from prior point releases.  Your source could be wrong.  In any case, you're not doing yourself any favors by trying to prevent updates.  Can you clarify if you are using 16.04 or 18.04?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I want to install Xilinx petalinux 2018.3 in Ubuntu 16.04.4 which is compatible. According to user guide Xilinx UG1144 (v2018.3), only Ubuntu 16.04.3 and Ubuntu 16.04.4 are compatible operating systems and not Ubuntu 16.04.5. Therefore, I would like to keep Ubuntu 16.04.4 without upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04.5.

Comment: The petalinux is a embedded linux operating system and is supported by Xilinx for development boards.

Comment: Hi, the reference is user guide Xilinx UG1144 (v2018.3).

Comment: If you are referring to page 10 on [this document](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_3/ug1144-petalinux-tools-reference-guide.pdf) which was written two years ago, you're incorrect in your assumptions.  The guide says under "Minimum workstation requirements": Ubuntu Linux 16.04.3, 16.04.4 (64-bit).  **It does not explicitly exclude subsequent point releases**.

Comment: As mentioned, 16.04 is still 16.04 no matter what [point release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/what-are-point-releases-in-lts-versions).  You should still keep your system updated.  You have until April 2021 to continue using 16.04.  At that point you will need to actually upgrade your system to 18.04.  But this document doesn't even suggest that you can't use 18.04.  16.04 is listed as a minimum requirement.

Comment: @engr_john there is no software that works on 18.04.4 that does not work on 18.04.5 Please keep upgrading 18.04.  It is the other way: software could be made for 18.04.5 that does not work on 18.04 and that than -has- to be about drivers and bugfixes. 18.04.5 = 18.04.4 with extra's,. It never removes functionality.

Comment: By the way: the installer of petalinux will also warn you about lacking support when installing: it tests during installation each component and sees if the requrements are matched.