# I have 20.04.3 but the lastest downloadable version is 20.04.2. What's the .3?

Tags: 20.04

According to `lsb_release -a`

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

What is 20.04.3 LTS? On the downloads page (http://www.releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/), the latest version is 20.04.2 LTS.

Why do I have 20.04.3 rather than 20.04.2?

Comment: The *release* date of 20.04.3 (26-August-2021) refers to the ISO release date for new downloads & installs. It's normal for installed systems to get it days-weeks ahead of the date (a *focal* system has reported as 20.04.3 for over a week now if I recall correctly).  This is expected; the RC for 20.04.3 has been out for a number of days now, and hopefully the current *release-candidate* will be the ISO that is released.

Comment: FYI:  The initial planned date of release for 20.04.3 was actually 19-August-2021, but due to some SHIM issues (delayed so fixes could be implemented which is now all done !), the release has been pushed back a week (releases are always a Thursday) thus the longer period of .3 for installed systems before the ISO release date, than occurs some *cycles*.

Answer (score 4):

The release date of 20.04.3 (*26-August-2021*) refers to the ISO release date for new downloads & installs.

It's normal for installed systems to get it days-weeks ahead of the date (a *focal* system has reported as 20.04.3 for over a week now if I recall correctly). This is expected; the RC for 20.04.3 has been out for a number of days now, and hopefully the current *release-candidate* will be the ISO that is released.

FYI: The initial planned date of release for 20.04.3 was actually 19-August-2021, but due to some [SHIM](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1937115) & like issues (*delayed so fixes could be implemented which is now all done* !), the release has been pushed back a week (releases are always a Thursday) thus the longer period of .3 for installed systems before the ISO release date, than occurs some *cycles*.

For full details of the 20.04.3 release; check out the [status tracker document](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/focal-fossa-20-04-3-lts-point-release-status-tracking/22948).

Answer (score 1):

20.04.3 already came through through the updates. As of today, 2021-08-22, the ISO download is indeed at version 20.04.02. It is probably a matter of days before the ISO of 20.04.3 will be made available from the [Ubuntu.com](https://ubuntu.com/) website.

See more information on the release schedule of Ubuntu [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/what-are-point-releases-in-lts-versions).