# Upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.04.x

Tags: drivers, upgrade, graphics, radeon

I've got a new graphic card from AMD - RX6900 - and currently having trouble with the drivers.

After taking a look over the AMD official driver support [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/previous-drivers/graphics/amd-radeon-6000-series/amd-radeon-6900-series/amd-radeon-rx-6900-xt), I see that the drivers are available for 20.04.1 20.04.2 and 20.04.3.

Currently I'm running on 20.04, no driver is working for this version unfortunately.

I tried to upgrade from Software Updater - but I get only 20.10 which I don't want.
Also tried to modify `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` to `Prompt=lts` but I still get 20.10.

Can someone please help me to upgrade to any of the versions mentioned above.

LE

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` returns

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease [115 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease [110 kB]
Fetched 326 kB in 1s (434 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Am I missing some repositories?

Comment: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: @Pilot6 `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: @Pilot6 added full log to question

Comment: So (1) if you installed all the regular updates you're already in 20.04.3 where 3 is just a point release and (2) AMD Graphics drivers are open-source, already installed and running, no user action required. What you found at AMD's website is a proprietary overlay that isn't necessary and any newbie is strongly recommended to NOT touch it. That proprietary overlay brings NO advantage for regular users not even for gaming. It may improve performance for very specific professional use and a couple of other very specific scenarios. So, just don't.

Comment: Also DON'T add the oibaf PPA. The best you can do now is probably install `ppa-purge` and run it against that PPA.

Comment: You have 21.04, not 20.04.

Comment: Run `cat /etc/lsb-release` and see.

Comment: @ChanganAuto my issue is that I run `llvmpipe` driver. I don't play games on ubuntu, it's work only. But I cannot run any software for blue light filter, not even Night Light from ubuntu... I had the same issue with the nvidia before, until I got the drivers it didn't work

Comment: This is a perfect example of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  Instead of asking how to solve your actual problem, you asked how to implement a proposed solution that isn't even relevant and wouldn't have solved your actual problem. Always ask about and provide details about your actual problem.  I suggest asking another question since this one is about something entirely different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `21.04` Ubuntu (hirsute) release installed and you have an option to upgrade to `21.10`, that is normal.

Can't you see the difference between `20.04` and `21.04`?

You can check by

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
```

Comment: you are right. I do run 21.04

Comment: 21.04 does not and will not have a point release. Point releases are only for LTS releases. Standard releases are only supported for 9 months and do not have a long enough service life to get point releases. Even with LTS versions, you don't actually upgrade to the next point release. Point releases exist to consolidate updates for new/fresh installations. All you need to do on an installed system is keep up with your regular updates as part of your system maintenance.  See: [What are point releases?](https://askubuntu.com/q/106159)