# Upgrade from 18.04.6 LTS to 20.04.0 (or 20.04.1)

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, kernel

We have a hosted Ubuntu VM that is running 18.04.6 LTS. The software that we need to run apparently only supports the 5.4 kernel or earlier, but we want to upgrade to 20.04 - so our options are 20.04.0 or 20.04.1. (it does not work at all with 20.04.4).
I thought I could possibly upgrade using the kernel version, but it looks like the 5.4 kernel applies to both 18.04 and 20.04.

Is there a way to indicate an interim release version with the "do-release-upgrade" command?

Comment: The short answer is no.

Comment: Point releases are not truly separate releases. See: [What are point releases?](https://askubuntu.com/q/106159)

Comment: you can possibly upgrade and then downgrade just the kernel, but that is not guaranteed to work without issues

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.4 using the GA kernel uses the 5.4 kernel, but Ubuntu 20.04.4 using the HWE kernel stack uses 5.13, when using 20.04.4 with an OEM stack the kernel used is..... i.e you're linking 20.04.x point release with the kernel stack details -  which are different things - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack .  My own boxes have multiple stacks installed (GA/HWE) so you aren't limited to just one either (*though some closed-source video drivers prevent multiple stacks co-existing*).  Thus if 18.04 had both GA (4.15) & HWE (5.4) you'd end up with GA (5.4) & HWE (5.13) in most

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ubuntu 20.04 with the 5.4 non-HWE kernel.

If you already upgraded to the 5.13 kernel you can easily install and use the 5.4 kernel.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

This will install the 5.4 kernel.

Then boot to this kernel using grub menu and uninstall the 5.13 kernel and headers using synaptic.