How to download GNUCash 5.8 on Ubuntu 22.04?
How to download GNUCash 5.8 for Ubuntu?
> $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

When I download GNUCash from "Ubuntu Software" I get version 4.8

It is my understanding that if I add another software repository I may be creating a mess?
$ grep -v '#' /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse


It's years since I used Gnucash, but I looked at their website and I don't see a software repository that contains a later version. I see an executable install file for 5.8 as well as instructions on how to use Flatpak to install a recent version. Why not try one of these options?

You report using 24.04 (noble) in the first line and 22.04 (jammy) later on. On 24.04 (noble) you get Gnucash 5.5.

This is possibly my 7th? fresh install of Ubuntu. I have decided to stop YOLOing it and breaking things and am trying to install only software that plays well with Ubuntu.  I have not tried the flatpak as I do not understand how it works and if I will be breaking something in the process?

"My OS is 24.04.4 LTS" Your apt output says you are running 22.04 ("jammy"), not 24.04 ("noble"). Your apt output shows that you are using 22.04 repositories, and Gnucash 4.8 is the version in those 22.04 repositories.

install flatpak in Ubuntu (it's quite safe to do so) see install and use Flatpak and it will give you version 5.8. Flatpaks are often updated more frequently than .deb versions and often found to have more recent versions.

I agree with @graham and would recommend using the Flatpak version.

You are definitely using 22.04.4 LTS, and not 24.04. By the way 24.04.4 does not even exist. The latest release is 24.04 with no further point release

No, installing flatpak should not break anything. I have explained how to set up flatpak in my answer below.

See https://askubuntu.com/q/106159/124466

What is the difference between "description" and "release?"

To install GNUCash 5.8 in Ubuntu 22.04, you can use Flatpak. Note that flatpak is a different packaging system, it does not mess with system packages. It does not require adding another APT repository.
First set up flatpak and its plugin for GNOME Software Center with the following commands (one by one).
sudo apt install flatpak

sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak

Add the flathub repository
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo

Finally, install GNUCash
flatpak install flathub org.gnucash.GnuCash

(alternatively, you could use GNOME Software to install the latest version of GNUCash from Flathub).
