# I have 3 updates that won't update

Tags: 12.04, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “dist-upgrade” and why does it upgrade more than “upgrade”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade)

The 3 updates are `generic linux kernel headers`, `generic linux kernel image`, and `open sound system (oss) compatibility package`. These 3 will not update.

Has any one else have or had this problem?

Comment: How are you updating your system? What version of Ubuntu is it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are updating your system via the terminal and you have updates that won't install you need to use another command.

`sudo apt-get upgrade` will not install updates that will install other new packages as dependencies or package removal for the installation of other packages: new kernels, new GRUB versions, etc will not be installed with it because they will do so. `apt-get upgrade` will only update packages currently installed in the system.

For updating packages that do changes to your system use either the *Update Manager* or in a terminal the command `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

First use:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And after that:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This might fix some errors if you have some errors

And check your update manager to see if some key or source should not be there or are wrong.