# Mismatch of packages to be updated between Update Manager (gui) and apt-get(cli)

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

I noticed my system acting weird today. While the update manager (gui application) states that there are ***14 updates selected, and 52 Mb will be downloaded,*** the `apt-get upgrade` command only informs me of ***1 update to be downloaded and installed***.

**The Update Manager Gui (output) can be found here:**
[image]

**and the cli `apt-get upgrade` output here:**

```
fokis@fokis-netbook:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  ginn libgrip0 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-headers-generic-pae
  linux-image-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-libc-dev
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 866 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.
```

**Note:** *I have run `apt-get update` before `apt-get upgrade` in the command line.*

***What is it that I am doing wrong?***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the CLI output you can see that some packages have been kept back, such as new kernel versions/headers. While *update-manager* installs them by default, `apt-get` requires the `dist-upgrade` parameter to include such packages in its upgrades.

Technically, `apt-get upgrade` will not install any *new* packages, e.g. `linux-image-...`, while `dist-upgrade` will. For more information on the differences between `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade` [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade).

Comment: Thank you. Is there a command line argument to allow me to manually select which packages to be installed.