# Why use apt-get upgrade instead of apt-get dist-upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, dist-upgrade

I usually use `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` to run my updates and upgrades instead of the GUI because it seems to run more quickly.

However, I've noticed lately that I often get a message that one of my upgrades was held back. I then usually run `dist-upgrade` to run it through and it works fine. As far as I can tell after reading [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade) and its answers, `dist-upgrade` does all the same things and then some.

So, my question is: Why use `apt-get upgrade` at all? Why not use `apt-get dist-upgrade` all the time? Why does `apt-get upgrade` even exist?

Comment: In newer Ubuntu versions, `sudo apt full-upgrade` does similar things.

Answer (score 534, accepted):

I typically upgrade my machines with:

```
sudo apt-get update && time sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Below is an excerpt from `man apt-get`. **Using upgrade keeps to the rule: under no circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages not already installed retrieved and installed.** If that's important to you, use `apt-get upgrade`. If you want things to "just work", you probably want `apt-get dist-upgrade` to ensure dependencies are resolved.

To expand on why you'd want *upgrade* instead of *dist-upgrade*, if you are a systems administrator, you need predictability. You might be using advanced features like [apt pinning](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) or pulling from a collection of [PPAs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) (perhaps you have an in-house PPA), with various automations in place to inspect your system and available upgrades instead of always eagerly upgrading all available packages. You would get very frustrated when apt performs unscripted behavior, particularly if this leads to downtime of a production service.

```
upgrade
    upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages
    currently installed on the system from the sources enumerated in
    /etc/apt/sources.list. Packages currently installed with new
    versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no
    circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages
    not already installed retrieved and installed. New versions of
    currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without
    changing the install status of another package will be left at
    their current version. An update must be performed first so that
    apt-get knows that new versions of packages are available.

dist-upgrade
    dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
    also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
    of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
    it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
    expense of less important ones if necessary. So, dist-upgrade
    command may remove some packages. The /etc/apt/sources.list file
    contains a list of locations from which to retrieve desired package
    files. See also apt_preferences(5) for a mechanism for overriding
    the general settings for individual packages.
```

Comment: Thank you for not only summing up the differences between the two, but also explaining the situations where one might be better than the other. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: `dist-upgrade` is more likely to break stuff badly than `upgrade`. `upgrade` ensures that your system remains complete.

Comment: dist-upgrade is more likely to fix issues with conflicting package versions, if you are comfortable with taking the road roller approach (i.e. you don't have a mission critical production software running on the box)

Comment: A small question about 'apt-get upgrade' refering to the fact that "no currently installed packages removed or new one added" : do existing packages get upgraded accordingly as well. For example oldA depends on oldB.  Will oldA and oldB both be upgraded ? How about if newA depends on oldB and not newB, what happens to these two during the upgrade ? both not upgraded or both upgraded, which may leaves newA not functioning because oldB is lost ?

Comment: What is the reason for using `time` here?

Comment: Informational. I opened the answer providing the command I typically use, to illustrate.

Comment: I'm a bit lost on the don't upgrade "if new package needs to be installed or one needs to be removed". I manage a deb package and as a test added a new package to the dependency list and removed another package from the dependeny list. I then copied the deb and ran "apt upgrade" and it will let me upgrade. Specifically it says "The following NEW packages will be installed" and 
"The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required". Can someone explain to me what I'm missing here? @rduplain

Comment: I too am seeking a reply to @shreddish's above question (from over 3 years ago). Thoughts?

Comment: `apt` != `apt-get`. Unfortunately, there's more than one way to do things, and it is indeed confusing. Especially because `apt-get` was the common way to do things in Debian systems for so long, before `apt` was available. Here, `apt upgrade` is not `apt-get upgrade` and does indeed install new packages (`man 8 apt`: "New packages will be installed if required to satisfy dependencies..."). As to the other question around "no longer required", APT (either command) will install packages to satisfy dependencies but won't remove them until running the `autoremove` subcommand.

Comment: @rduplain Indeed apt is not apt-get. You might want to extend your answer with `apt`.

Answer (score 175):

I know this question has been answered and is a year old, but I feel this needs to be said. Ubuntu 14.04 and later (and Debian Jessie and later, for those finding this from Google) uses APT 1.0, which allows the command `apt` instead of `apt-get` and `apt-cache` for some operations.

- `apt-get upgrade` will not change what is installed (only versions),
- `apt-get dist-upgrade` will install or remove packages as necessary to complete the upgrade,
- `apt upgrade` will automatically install but not remove packages.
- `apt full-upgrade` performs the same function as `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: @muru Thanks for the edit and the note about full-upgrade. I primarily use Debian 7 (which is pre-APT 1.0), and I've only played with Debian Jessie and Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: you're welcome. As someone who does used `jessie` and 14.04 regularly, I first learned of this new utility from your answer!

Comment: Do you have a source for your description of `apt upgrade`? Everything I can come up with suggests that `apt upgrade` is the same as `apt-get upgrade`. For example, `apt help upgrade` on my system outputs: `"apt upgrade" is equivalent to "sudo apt-get upgrade"`

Comment: The respective manpages for `apt` and `apt-get` specify what I originally said.

Comment: So is `apt safe-upgrade` equivalent to `apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: `apt safe-upgrade` is not a valid operation on my system. If you mean `aptitude safe-upgrade`, not quite. `apt-get upgrade` will never install packages, whereas `apt upgrade` and `aptitude safe-upgrade` will install new packages as dependencies demand it. So `aptitude safe-upgrade` is equivalent to `apt upgrade`, not `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: @JonBentley, In Ubuntu 18.04, `apt help upgrade` now says `upgrade - upgrade the system by installing/upgrading packages`

Comment: It seems that `apt upgrade` is enough.

Comment: @Timo If `apt upgrade` were "enough", we wouldn't have anything else. `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` / `apt full-upgrade` have different purposes again. Now if `apt upgrade` is enough for you most of the time, fine, but every distinct command has its use.

Comment: @StephenAngelico I hope there is only one `apt update`..

Answer (score 10):

The `upgrade` option only installs new version of the packages that are already installed on the system (and yes, kernel updates belong to them).

However, sometimes the updates change dependencies: for example, a new version of a package will no longer depend on a library that you have installed, or will require installation of additional libraries. The `upgrade` option will never remove installed packages that you no longer actually need.

However, the `dist-upgrade` option can "intelligently" handle changes in the dependencies system. This includes removing packages that are no longer necessary or resolve conflicts between packages that arose because of changes in the dependencies.

Comment: While this is accurate, I don't think it answers the question. If we have an "intelligent" option that can handle dependency changes and remove clutter, why not always use it?

Comment: `upgrade` will also never *add* new packages that *become* needed as dependencies. From [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html): "under no circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages not already installed retrieved and installed" @ændrük Just because something is "intelligent" doesn't mean it will always do what the user wants (or even something at all reasonable). Anytime a system update *removes* a package, it's good to look over what it's doing before pressing Y.

Comment: Are you talking about `apt-get` or `apt`? Since your answer is now getting ambiguous..?

Answer (score 3):

Users might have come to rely on packages that were installed implicitly because of other (explicitly installed) packages' dependency on them.  Thus the packaging system cannot be aware of a user/administrator desire to retain certain functionality that might otherwise be removed via dist-upgrade.