# Why did my PHP5.5 upgrade fail?

Tags: php

I have a relatively new install of Ubuntu 12.04.  The php version is 5.3, so I just followed this question to upgrade to 5.5: [How do I install different (upgrade or downgrade) PHP version in still supported Ubuntu release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1)

When I ran the final command though (`sudo apt-get upgrade`), it gave me the following output:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done The following packages have been kept back: 
>   apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2.2-bin libapache2-mod-php5 libjson0
>   php5-cli php5-common php5-mysql 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to
>   remove and 8 not upgraded.

Why does it 'keep packages back'?

Comment: It can be beacuse their dependencies cannot be met or installing them will unistall something else non-repleaceble with new versions of same package. What does it answer when you try to install them manually?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

More info here:
[Why use apt-get upgrade instead of apt-get dist-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade)