# Why is Ubuntu repeatedly asking me to upgrade?

Tags: installation, versions

Hello there I have recently downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 and installed it alongside with my windows7. After I finished my installation it asked me to upgrade and I upgraded but after that my Ubuntu desktop became 12.10. Now again it asks me to upgrade to 13.04.

I am really confused cause as on the Ubuntu download center it is stated that Ubuntu 12.04 will have support till 2017.

What is really happening? Do I need to upgrade every time it asks me to upgrade or can I skip the upgrade. And what will happen to my first installed Ubuntu 12.04 version? Will it have support till 2017?

I am really a beginner with Linux and Ubuntu.

Comment: Basically, some versions are released as "Long Term Support" versions that will receive continued updates for a long time. The update tool probably just by default nags you to update to the latest version. It is perfectly fine to stick with 12.04 and ignore bids to install to higher versions. See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

Comment: Your 12.04 LTS version has been upgraded to 12.10. This means that it will no longer be supported until 2017. Ubuntu is asking you to upgrade because 12.04 is not the "most recent stable version" and you have configured it to do so, as mentioned below.

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu have two different release types

- Normal releases come out every six months and the next one 13.10 is due out tomorrow.  Normal releases are supported for 9 months
- **LTS** (Long Term Stable) releases come out every two years and are supported for 5 years.  12.04 is the latest LTS release and is supported until April 2017.

The reason for the two different release types is that LTS releases remain stable for a long time so are useful for business and for those users who don't want to keep updating their system.  The Normal releases allow users to try all the latest features so that when the next LTS release comes out everything has been well tested for users who prize stability over new features.

Many people such as myself only use LTS releases for day to day work and don't rush to install the next LTS release.

If you have only recently installed Ubuntu you may want to reinstall 12.04 so you don't have to keep updating.

Run the update manager select Preferences and make sure **Notify me of a new Ubuntu version** is set to <kbd>For long-term support versions</kbd> as shown.

You will then not be notified of a new version until April 2014 and you can choose to update at any time you choose from then until support runs out in 2017.

[image]

Comment: You've just posted what I was going to post, but with better explanation. :) Nice..!!

Answer (score 2):

12.04 will be supported until 2017. 
For someone new to Ubuntu I would suggest sticking with that.

Since you already upgraded and this is a fresh install (I assume), the easiest thing to do is reinstall Ubuntu 12.04. Since you have 12.10 installed, this time when you install from the liveCD you will have the option to replace the current 12.10 installation with 12.04. Do That. Then if you are ever asked to upgrade simply say No.

Answer (score -2):

Read this Links you will came to know About the Difference Between upgrade and dist-upgrade

[What is “dist-upgrade” and why does it upgrade more than “upgrade”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade)

Why use apt-get upgrade instead of apt-get dist-upgrade?

[Click here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade)