# 29 packages can be updated - How?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I see the following message when I login:

> 29 packages can be updated.
>
> 6 updates are security updates.

**How can I perform the updates?**

I tried `apt-get upgrade` and some stuff was installed but the message still remains.

Comment: post the output of `sudo apt-get -s upgrade`

Comment: This has good explanation - https://askubuntu.com/a/1104324/330608

Answer (score 198):

Try these commands (although the third one may not be necessary for you):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

A reboot may or may not be necessary (`sudo shutdown -r 0`)

Comment: Why `dist-upgrade` *before* `update`?

Comment: Try another order: `update`, `upgrade`, `dist-upgrade` and it makes no difference.

Comment: This is really wrong. You only need to run `upgrade` or `dist-upgrade`, not both, and `update` always comes first.

Comment: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` did it for me

Comment: I'm running all these commands in every order and I think my computer is not on fire so we are good.

Comment: @einnocent I think the point is you might only have to type 2 or 3 of the commands.  Obviously you can type 18 lines because there are 6 ways to order the commands and 3 commands each time, but you'd rather just type **2** or **3**

Comment: I'm guessing @EliahKagan is right because his reputation is the highest

Comment: Also, reboot was necessary for me on `gcloud compute`.

Comment: apt-get upgrade will not change what is installed (only versions), apt-get dist-upgrade will install or remove packages as necessary to complete the upgrade, apt upgrade will automatically install but not remove packages. apt full-upgrade performs the same function as apt-get dist-upgrade (https://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade)

Comment: I'm sorry but this type of answer and comments list are a compelte voodoo and not a disciplined way of exploring and fixing up a system.

Answer (score 97):

When you ran `apt-get upgrade`, where there any "not upgraded"? Eg:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Looking at `0 not upgraded`. If there were ones that were not upgraded, run `apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Its not working. Still 11 not upgraded.