# How to update those packages

Tags: package-management

How do i get those 52 packeges updated?

i give a `sudo apt-get update` but still it all remains.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-138-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

52 packages can be updated.
9 updates are security updates.
```

Comment: *update* updates your machines list of packages available, upgrade will *upgrade* your packages (within certain restrictions), *dist-upgrade* (or *full-upgrade*) upgrades all packages to latest available.

Answer (score 5):

`sudo apt-get update` does **NOT** install your updates.  It only gets the list of packages available for installation.

You need to run `sudo apt upgrade` to actually do the installation of updated packages.  If it still does not do all the updates, then whatever is being installed pulls in some other packages than just those specific packages that need updated and you have to approve the installation step via `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and its prompts.