# 14.04 media server, general questions, Force Boot, Lean Running, Auto Updates..

Tags: boot, server

I have setup Ubuntu 14.04 desktop as a media server, I know, I know, should have gone with server.. I wanted the GUI though. I have a few questions..

1) Is there anything I can disable or trim down to make it more lean in running? (I know.. should have used server)

2) Is there a way to make it always attempt to fully boot no matter what errors it encounters during the boot? I VNC in remotely and it's a major pain if it doesn't boot to at least the point where VNC loads. For instance, I changed some mount settings and mispelled something while at work, I rebooted and it was just dead because I needed to hit "S" to skip mounting that drive. I want it to just ignore everything it encounters and try to boot every time.

3) Is there an auto update system I could use so that it auto updates and reboots once a week at some time I determine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nobootwait` [flag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53456/what-is-the-difference-between-nobootwait-and-nofail-in-fstab) in your `fstab` to have the system continue to boot if mounting fails. There is also a `timeo` (timeout) option that might work.

To auto update and reboot you can use a [cron job](http://crontab.org/). To do this add an entry to the system crontab `sudo vim /etc/crontab`. All this stuff takes root privileges so have the command run as root.

To update and reboot every Sunday at 1am would be something like this.

```
m   h    dom    mon   dow   user    command
0   1     *      *     0    root    apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && shutdown -r now
```

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade -y` is better than `apt-get upgrade -y`. See [Why use apt-get upgrade instead of apt-get dist-upgrade?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade)

Comment: How would one find and then edit the fstab? Sorry, I am still very much a Linux noob.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab