# Is it recommended to do apt-get upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

Should anyone running Ubuntu  as a normal user (not a server) do any of:

```
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt upgrade
```

regularly? I am asking because running `apt update && apt upgrade` has led to issues for me in the past. The system works fine when I do not upgrade, but I don't know if this may cause any (security) issues later on. I am aware [what the difference between this commands is](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade), but I do not know and could not find any best practices regarding their usage.

According to this post, "Many recommend that when doing a CLI update, all three commands be used":

```
sudo apt-get update        # Fetches the list of available updates
sudo apt-get upgrade       # Strictly upgrades the current packages
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  # Installs updates (new ones)
```

Which raises the question, in what case should I do a 'CLI update'? I like to have an up-to-date system, but not at the cost of weird issues. I am afraid that upgrading this way will cause the same issue. A more practical subquestion is: how can I upgrade my system without the virtualbox-guest-dkms, virtualbox-guest-utils, and virtualbox-guest-x11 packages (I suspect the problem is in one of those, and I'm not sure why I'd need them, so I'd rather just not have them).

Comment: Dist upgrade will give you Ubuntu version upgrade. If you are happy with the version you have, and more important if you have LTS release, then i wouldnt recommend doing dist upgrade. As for upgrade, that gives you newest version of programs.

Comment: Problems related to Mint should be asked on http://unix.stackexchange.com/