# Is apt-get dist-upgrade required in Docker container?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, docker

[Node Source's Docker image of Ubuntu](https://github.com/nodesource/docker-node/blob/master/ubuntu/trusty/node/4.4.0/Dockerfile) runs `apt-get upgrade`, not `apt-get dist-upgrade`, to install latest version of all packages.

`apt-get dist-upgrade` is considered a command to upgrade kernel related packages. In Docker container, kernel packages are not installed because host's kernel is used, and `apt-get upgrade` looks enough.

However, man page of `apt-get` says:

```
dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
of packages
```

According to this, other packages may require to run `apt-get dist-upgrade` to install latest patch.

Are there such packages which requires `apt-get dist-upgrade` in the current or past releases of Ubuntu?
If such packages exists, we need to run `dist-upgrade` even in Docker container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you are going to want to use upgrade rather then dist-upgrade.

In general, unless you have a problem or feel you know more then the docker developers, best go with the defaults.

In the event upgrade has problems, dist-upgrade is a potential solution.

upgrade will update new packages when new versions are available, but will sometimes not remove packages or not install additional packages. dist-upgrade will upgrade and if necessary add or remove packages.

You should always review what apt-get is telling you when you upgrade and review the packages list with dist-upgrade.

For additional information see

[What is "dist-upgrade" and why does it upgrade more than "upgrade"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade)

and

[Why use apt-get upgrade instead of apt-get dist-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

I would say you should not even use `upgrade`: rather rebuild the image with `--no-cache` and execute the usual `update` and `install` pair, which will fetch the latest versions of a package.

Comment: Why this approach is better?

Comment: `install` will get the latest version of packages that you need; as for the already installed packages, they will come with the latest tag of the base image you start from, as long as it's maintained.