# Can't upgrade to 16.04 from 15.10

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 15.10, do-release-upgrade

I just started following [this digitalocean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts) and did every step until the `do-release-upgrade` part.

However I get

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release 
No new release found
```

I've tried `sudo do-release-upgrade` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can upgrade to 16.04 LTS, using software and update or terminal

### Software and update

In software and update window on the 3rd tab you can find the os updates just click install.

[Update Ubuntu using software and update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbSF6.png)

### Terminal

Check this article hope that I helps you

For short here are some commads to do upgrade from ubuntu 15.10 wily werewolf to ubuntu 16.04 xenial xerus (LTS), open a new Terminal and type them one by one

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

at last :

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

and click upgrade and continue by choosing upgrade and start upgrade till it starts upgrading

Comment: This worked! BTW why did I have to install `dist-upgrade`?

Comment: My third tab does not look like that screenshot. No luck from either method.

Comment: ... Hmm, eventually, after many re-tries fiddling with the updater settings, it seems like changing the upgrade setting from "long-term-support versions" to "all versions" got it to find 16.04, though that doesn't make much sense since 16.04 is LTS, no?

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure why you had to install `dist-upgrade`, check [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/226213/497723) hope that it helps.

Comment: @Dronz Why no luck? Give more information about what you have.

Comment: @MehdiShahamirian As in my second comment, it seems it was not showing me 16.04 until I set upgrades to "all versions" rather than "long-term-support versions", but that doesn't make sense to me, as I think 16.x is a long-term-support version, so I would expect it to show it to me with that setting. But I believe I only made that one change during the session where it then offered to upgrade to 16.04. Seems like a bug or at least a very confusing UI wording.