# E:The package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-37-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: package-management

When I tried to install `testdrive` on my ubuntu by using terminal this message appeared:

```
E:The package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-37-generic needs to be reinstalled
```

and I can't find an archive for it.
Then i went to google and tried to find some solution and found that I have to change something in software sources when I went there I found an alert message

```
"this is a serious problem please inform developer"
```

and in details it was written `"E:The package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-37-generic needs to be reinstalled` but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

The `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-37-generic` package [was deleted from the Ubuntu repositories](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/canonical_kernel_team/trusty/main/base/linux-image-extra-4.4.0-37-generic) at September 7th of 2016.

I suppose you are trying to install the [Ubuntu's QA Testdrive](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QATeam/Testdrive) using `apt-get`. I Think you must upgrade your system before trying to install the software.

To upgrade your Ubuntu (probably a 14.04), you may try [a `dist-upgrade` instead of a simple upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then install the Testdrive

```
sudo apt-get install testdrive
```