# Update Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

I would like to know if it is possible to update from Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point release upgrades (16.04.x to 16.04.y) are generally applied automatically whenever you update and upgrade the system from either "Software Updater" app or terminal/command line. To update from terminal/command line, run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

To check which version you are currently using, either go to **Settings → Details** or open terminal and run:

```
lsb_release -a
```