# Install Jasmin Gateway on Ubuntu Server

Tags: 16.04, server, software-installation, dependencies, gateway

I am trying to install Jasmin Gateway on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS, but I have the error below:

```
root@ds234:/home# sudo apt-get install python-jasmin                         
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-jasmin : Depends: rabbitmq-server but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install rabbitmq-server:

```
root@ds234:/home/prodadmin# sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rabbitmq-server : Depends: locales-all
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to run the commands below to fix the broken packages but did not install:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt remove
```

Comment: Please review the unmet dependencies issue in https://askubuntu.com/a/142808/197910 and held back packages in https://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade . You can also insert search terms in the search bar up top where you see "Search on Ask Ubuntu" to find results for key phrases like "unmet dependencies" and "held back" then click on the Votes button right of center to sort out the answers found helpful by the most folks. That's why it's important to click on the up arrow and the checkmark on answers which solve problems.