# Dist-upgrade damaged OS. Should i reinstall Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, package-management, updates, dependencies, system

I was having problems updating my Ubuntu 20.4. Even partial update was not working it was showing error like you don't have ubuntu-desktop and can't detect version of Ubuntu etc. So online i found a command `dist-upgrade` which updates the OS and solves all the problems related to update so without thinking twice i used that command. It removed my system apps settings and update-manager. So now everything is working fine but now there is no GUI app to check for updates and when i check for updates using terminal, 3 updates are held back including security updates. And i was successful to reinstall settings app but update-manager is not installing i get following error -

***The following packages have unmet dependencies:
update-manager : Depends: update-manager-core (= 1:20.04.9) but 1:20.04.10.5 is to be installed
Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.***

I tried everything that i found online to correct this problem all commands related to ***apt, dpkg, aptitude,*** etc but the problem is still unsolved. Ultimately i think i have to reinstall Ubuntu. I have dual boot setup and if i reinstall OS will my current apps, data, and themes get deleted?

Since i do not have any GUI app to check for updates i use terminal commands `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade` all updates happen normally without error but only three updates are held back every time i get this error when updating from terminal -
***The following packages have been kept back:
kiwix libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.***

Then i tried `sudo aptitude upgrade` and got this error message-
***No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.***

Tried updating with `apt -f` but still not solved.

Comment: Try reinstalling it with formating the disk.

Comment: The way you have worded your question reveals that you have some misconceptions: *"I found a command `dist-upgrade` which updates the OS and solves all the problems related to update ..."* There isn't any "magic command" that solves all problems - this is a fundamentally dangerous way to think. Instead, [learn what `dist-upgrade` actually do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade) - and backtrack your actions to why some apps might have been removed.

Comment: Those mismatched dependency version numbers are typically caused by and out of date package list. First, run `sudo apt update`. Also, the error message you posted should continue and tell you how to fix the problem so do what the error message says: `sudo apt -f install` Please post the results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use apt-get upgrade instead of apt-get dist-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/q/194651/) and [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)