# Will apt-get dist-upgrade upgrade my system to a newer version?

Tags: apt

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 right now. If I use the command `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` will that upgrade my Ubuntu to 12.10? Does that mean I won't be using the LTS version after that? I don't want to use Ubuntu 12.10 because I've already tried it and it's very heavy for my netbook.

Answer (score 189):

You can read the man-page of `apt-get` to see what each command do.

Open the manual

```
man apt-get
```

Find the section `dist-upgrade` and read

> dist-upgrade
>
> ```
>        in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
>        also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
>        of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
>        it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
>        expense of less important ones if necessary. So, dist-upgrade
>        command may remove some packages. The /etc/apt/sources.list file
>        contains a list of locations from which to retrieve desired package
>        files. See also apt_preferences(5) for a mechanism for overriding
>        the general settings for individual packages
> ```

See also: [What is “dist-upgrade” and why does it upgrade more than “upgrade”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade)

In order to upgrade Ubuntu to a newer release you have to run in terminal

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

We read from the [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/do-release-upgrade)

```
man do-release-upgrade
```

> DESCRIPTION
>
> Upgrade  the  operating  system  to  the  latest  release from the
>   command-line.  This is the preferred command if the machine has
>   no graphic    environment  or  if the machine is to be upgraded over a
>   remote connection

Comment: I'd love a TL;DR; too, though

Comment: If you prefer a nice GUI, use:  
`sudo do-release-upgrade -f GTK`

Comment: TL;DR; No it won't

Answer (score 100):

No, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` will not upgrade to a new Ubuntu release. It will just install available updates for the Ubuntu release you already have installed.

Unlike `sudo apt-get upgrade` it may install new packages or remove installed packages if that is necessary to satisfy dependencies. So be careful when using it.

Comment: what do you mean by remove installed packages? why it remove installed packages? So how suppose I use dist-upgrade?

Comment: It may remove a package if there's a conflict between packages or dependencies that can't be satisfied. Usually you don't need to use `dist-upgrade`. It may be useful if `upgrade` tells you that some packages are hold back, but you should carefully review what it wants to do, especially if it want to remove packages.

Comment: I'll claim this answer is false. If the `/etc/apt/sources.list*` has been altered to point to a new release, then `apt-get dist-ugprade` indeed _will_ (attempt to) upgrade to a new release. Not something that is likely to happen to a casual user, though.

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch In fact, the do-release-upgrade tool does exactly that: update the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list, disables or modifies the extras in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and then calls apt-get dist-upgrade.

Comment: I think the concepts are inverted.

Answer (score 10):

If you do not want to upgrade to non-LTS versions, follow these steps:

- Open **Ubuntu Software Center**.
- Go to *Edit* -> *Software Sources*.
- Go to the *Updates* tab and make sure you have selected *For long-term support versions* in the *Notify of a new Ubuntu version*.

[image]

- Open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get update` (just to be sure :) ).
- Now, when you run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` it'd be upgraded to the next LTS version and not non-LTS versions.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16 this program is called `Software & Updates`

Comment: How do you do this operation from the command line?

Comment: From command line: `software-properties-gtk`

Answer (score 8):

you cannot jump from 12.04 to 13.04 directly you would have to have update manger set to normal then do

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

or

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

the difference between the commands is that dist-upgrade wants you to change your config files during the upgrade

they both will upgrade your dist when the time comes 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
only upgrades the software on your system it does not install or remove packages like dist-upgrade.

Comment: If you are running an alternative desktop like cinnamon or mate and you run do-release upgrade it will remove cinnamon and keep the config files and your system will break cause it's looking for cinnamon and it's not there if you ran dist-upgrade it will change the config files system will remove cinnamon and system will use gnome 3 instead you would have reinstall the desktop after doing the upgrade though