# How to upgrade ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS in Dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot

I am using dual operating systems (windows 7 ultimate + Ubuntu 12.04) now i want to upgrade Ubuntu to 14.04.can i directly boot again and replace the old version.i am trying to update from update manager but its is upgrading to 12.10.please let me know if it is possible to replace or shall i continue with update manager.

Thank you

Comment: Through command line : sudo do-release-upgrade .

Source: [NikTh answer][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/215267/will-apt-get-dist-upgrade-upgrade-my-system-to-newer-version

Answer (score 0):

you can upgrade it without any trouble

& if something happens you can fix it with grub

updating

First things first: make sure that you are fully up-to-date. Double check by opening the Update Manager application from the dash and installing all updates listed

```
$ sudo update-manager -d
```

click upgrade

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Can i replace directly from ubuntu12.04 lts to 14.04 lts again by booting