# Google Search garbled on Firefox on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, firefox, fonts

I recently updated Firefox on Ubuntu 14.04. I also installed some fonts on Ubuntu after that.

After this, the google search on firefox looks like this:

[image]

I've tried explicitely going to google.com and then searching, still same problem occurs.

Yahoo and other search engines work fine though.

After searching web, I tried using following things, but none work:

1. Change language of firefox.
2. Change font of firefox.
3. Reinstall firefox from ubuntu center.
4. `sudo rm -rf ~/.mozilla` (to completely reset firefox)
5. Remove firefox, perform step 4, install firefox from ubuntu center.

But none seems to work. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: When you changed the font in Firefox, there's a checkbox to make your choice override site preferences. Did you try that?

Comment: @muru No it doesn't work!

Comment: Could add a screenshot of Firefox, after having right-clicked on a text element on a google page in Firefox, and selecting the Fonts tab? ([example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OqwUL.png))

Comment: Which fonts did you install and where did you get them? Could you try to remove them (but write them down so you can reinstall if needed) and reboot the entire system (to be safe)?

Comment: Are there "arial" and "sans-serif" among those fonts you've installed? (Google doesn't seem to use web fonts; it uses arial and alternatively sans-serif from your local fonts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the problem is caused by either an unsupported font or unsupported language.

Click Edit->Preferences->Content

You should get this:

[image: ff1]

Choose default font serif. If this doesn't resolve the issue after restarting firefox, you may also wish to check languages by clicking the Choose Button highlighted above and changing to English for testing purposes

This action will result in this:

[image: ff2]

When visiting google.in I also noticed the page is available in a number of languages which you can choose by clicking on a link on that page. It's possible you have a mismatch between the language chosen on that page and the language chosen in firefox.

Comment: Thanks, works! Idk how but changing font works even though I tried it before.

Comment: Glad to help. No Thank you comments are required (they are actually discouraged here). Your acceptance of the answer is thanks enough!

Answer (score 1):

1.The complement of apt-get install package is apt-get remove package. To remove all associated settings too, you need to run apt-get purge package.

Remove orphaned packages

[A graphical tool to find and remove orphaned libraries](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gtkorphan/)

[refer here to pulge package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package)

[this should also help you](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1215352)

[here is another link to completely remove firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16758/removing-firefox-in-ubuntu-with-all-add-ons-like-it-never-existed)

2.Note that these commands rely on the uninstallation scripts provided with the package. All packages in the main repository I know of do their job of uninstalling very well. This may not be the case for third-party packages or browsers.

as for removing 3rdparty/dependency packages software you may try:

Synaptic Package Manager by means of the Ubuntu Software Center.

Click on the grey Ubuntu logo (Dash home).
Query: synaptic
Click on Synaptic Package Manager

3.or perhaps system restore would work:

As for the "System rollback" / "System Restore" features, the closest feature you'll get is a system image using software like Clonezilla. Unfortunately, this cannot be done within a running system and must be performed from a Live CD.

Answer (score -1):

Try running this on terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge firefox*; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get autoremove; sudo apt-get autoclean; sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Comment: Why not just `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox\*`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster false! FYI dist-upgrade is not a distribution upgrade tool. It just upgrades the current distribution to the latest available you might wanna check again http://askubuntu.com/questions/215267/will-apt-get-dist-upgrade-upgrade-my-system-to-newer-version. 
He was trying to reinstall firefox anyway, he didn't purge all the settings. Just showed him a better way.

Comment: You're right. I don't know where I got that idea.

Comment: doesn't helps :|