# Upgrade Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: upgrade, 11.04

I've a question about upgrading my old Ubuntu 11.04 to the latest version.
How can I do this without loosing my settings and data?

Comment: This question has been asked before, I suggest you make a backup and follow the instructions to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Ubuntu 11.04 release has reached "End of Life", it could take additional steps to upgrade. Ubuntu Documentation has article describing the process:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

The steps are:

1. Determine if backup required (and make one) if things go wrong.
2. Make sure you have the following lines at `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

   `deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted universe multiverse`

   `deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted universe multiverse`

   `deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security main restricted universe multiverse`
3. Update the package list and upgrade all the installed packages:

   `sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude safe-upgrade`
4. Perform the release upgrade:

   `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Answer (score -1):

Please using the below command and check the new update available for upgrade,

```
lsb_release -a
```

After checking the update, try with the below commands and upgrade the ubuntu to latest version,

```
 sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade` [doesn't upgrades](http://askubuntu.com/q/215267/65926) Ubuntu from an older to a newer version.