# why can't I install some packages after installing virtualbox

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates

After I installed virtualbox, I cannot install some packages. So I removed virtualbox, then I still cannot install the packages.

- This is the package:

  [image]
- And this is the error I received.

  [image]
- After I ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, there is no error and the result is as this:

  [image]
- After I ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, I was asked to install `libav-tools`, then I chose `y`, and then the error appeared.

  [image]

Comment: Could you try upgrading from a terminal (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`) and add any error messages to your question, please? This would help more than a error message only saying "There's something wrong, but I won't tell you what."

Comment: [sudo apt-get dist-upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/215267/will-apt-get-dist-upgrade-upgrade-my-system-to-newer-version)

Comment: @the_Seppi  hi, there, I have edited the question. There is no error message by running your command.

Comment: Can you please provide output in a copyable form, not as an image.

Comment: are you sure your drive has enough source to install new packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is the short answer.

```
sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

Comment: hi, I still cannot solve it and also I find one more error. I have updated the question.

Comment: Please add a list of your repositories and replace the graphics in your question through the text output of programs.

Comment: What is output when you run a `sudo aptitude remove ffmpeg`? **Answer the security question with 'N'**!

Comment: Hi, the problem is that the version of ffmpeg I install conflicted with libav-tools. After I removed my ffmpeg, I can install libav-tools and everything becomes fine. Thanks. but could you please edit your answer?

Comment: @A.B. downvote was from me, when I did it your answer was different.

Comment: Very short answer! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and if that doesn't help

```
cd /tmp    
wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hwloc/libhwloc-plugins_1.8-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libhwloc-plugins_1.8-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Rickter, hi, I still cannot solve it and also I find one more error. I have updated the question.

Comment: @tqjustc Please edit your question as suggested in my last comment to it.

Answer (score -1):

The screenshots are somewhat limited in what they show, but can you try the following,

Visit the answer below and follow the steps to get the default sources for apt. Can't tell if you have added any.

[How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

( alternative http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/01/restore-your-sources-list-to-defaults.html )

Just to be sure, remove the left overs of lib-avtools,

```
apt-get remove lib-avtools
```

&

```
apt-get clean
```

Try again,

```
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If it fails again, is there any more information in `/var/log/dpkg.log?`