# How to install GLIBCXX_3.4.29 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, dependencies, games, lts, shared-library

I downloaded DOOM BFA Version 1.2.8 but after running I got the message:

> ./DoomBFA: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version
> `GLIBCXX_3.4.29 'not found (required by ./DoomBFA)

Is there any way to update these libraries in ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Have you installed all the dependencies? https://github.com/MadDeCoDeR/Classic-RBDOOM-3-BFG

Comment: I installed dependencies, and after a failed compilation attempt, I downloaded the compiled version.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/215267/will-apt-get-dist-upgrade-upgrade-my-system-to-a-newer-version

Comment: GLIBCXX_3.4.29 is an object from `libstdc++.so.6.0.29` . Supplied with g++-11. Example PPA https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test

Comment: Thank you Knud Larsen for the link, this solves the problem with libraries. greetings

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Translated into practical steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt install -y g++-11
```

Then check if the version appears in the list:

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```

Resource:
https://lindevs.com/install-g-on-ubuntu

Comment: you saved me from losing my sanity. Thank you

Comment: This worked for me. I had issues with pytorch. This fixed it.

Comment: Thanks. I needed to `sudo apt-get update` between the 2 commands.

Comment: Should I just skip to -13 now?

Answer (score 1):

Library for ubuntu 20.04 that updates to [libstdc++.so.6.0.29](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test)

the wanted version.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/glibc