# Does Ubuntu Update across Versions?

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

I am depending on running the following script (as an cronjob every week) for all my update of ubuntu focal fossa.

```
# To make the script exit upon error
set -e

# Now carry on with the update and upgrade
apt-get --assume-yes --fix-missing update
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get --assume-yes --fix-broken install
apt-get --assume-yes upgrade
apt-get --assume-yes dist-upgrade
apt-get --assume-yes full-upgrade
apt-get --assume-yes autoremove
apt-get --assume-yes clean
```

I just wonder, since it includes something like dist-upgrade and full-upgrade, does it mean my focal-fossa will be automatically updated to the more recent jellyfish version? If so, does it make Ubuntu a rolling distro, just like manjaro?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will apt-get dist-upgrade upgrade my system to a newer version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215267/will-apt-get-dist-upgrade-upgrade-my-system-to-a-newer-version)

Comment: *since it includes something like dist-upgrade and full-upgrade, does it mean my focal-fossa will be automatically updated to the more recent jellyfish version?* No, of course not, such information can be very easily googled, and those are redundant! This stems from a very poor understanding of what the commands do, lack of updated knowledge - use of the old `apt-get` instead of `apt` - and you don't depend on such "script" to keep the system updated, no one does.

Comment: You're using a *stable* system (ie. the second latest LTS release*.  If you want a *rolling* system, Ubuntu can use *rolling rhino*, but you need to specifically select to use that, with the upgrade needing to be made from current *development* release which is *five* releases newer than your *focal*, ie. you upgrade to *rolling rhino* from *kinetic*  (focal, gorilla, hirsute, impish, jammy, kinetic... you're a very old-stable system currently with focal)

Comment: Automating repair (`--fix missing` and `--fix broken`) seems wasted effort: Apt cannot autofix network problems nor resolve breaks that are unwisely introduced by a human admin. Running both `dist-upgrade` and `full-upgrade` seems pointless. Pick the  correct command and run it only when appropriate lest a human admin's mistake with sources devastate your system.

Answer (score 0):

Your script will not upgrade to a different Ubuntu release. (Unless you modify your /etc/apt/sources.list)

For upgrading to a new release you have:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

[See the Ubuntu man page for do-release-upgrade](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html)

You might want to use apt instead of apt-get. I think apt-get full-upgrade does not even exist.

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Will upgrade your existing packages if it can without removing or adding packages (in case of a change in dependencies)

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Will do everything that the normal upgrade command does, and additionally might remove/add packages if required in order to upgrade.

I believe the "sudo apt-get upgrade" is redundant in your script and can be removed. The "sudo apt-get full-upgrade" can be changed to "sudo apt full-upgrade", so the "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" can be removed as well.

Comment: Nitpicking: the link refers to the `man` page of the `do-release-upgrade` command, where `man` stands for _manual_ (as in: handbook), not for _manage_.

Comment: Whoops, I typed this on my phone. Apparently "manpage" was autocorrected to manage. I'll edit, thanks :)